# setInterval not processing properly

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

What I am trying to do is check my CodeIgniter every 2 seconds to see if the session is still alive. But for some reason when I use the following code I get this error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ;"

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Javascript:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/sessionExpire"), function(data) {
            var sessionState = jQuery.parseJSON('{"sessionExpired":"true","sessionExpired":"false"}');
            if(sessionState.sessionExpired === "true") {
                alert('expired');
            } else if(sessionState.sessionExpired == "false") {
                alert('not expired');
            }
        });
}, 2000);
```

Ci code:

```php
public function sessionExpire() {
    if ($this->session->userdata("logged") == "1") {
        echo json_encode(array("sessionExpired" => false));
    } elseif($this->session->userdata("logged") == "0") {
        echo json_encode(array("sessionExpire" => true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had an extra parenthesis here:

```
$.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/sessionExpire") // <--
```

This should work:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/sessionExpire", function(data) {
        var sessionState = $.parseJSON('{"sessionExpired":"true","sessionExpired":"false"}');
        if (sessionState.sessionExpired === "true") {
            alert('expired');
        } else if (sessionState.sessionExpired == "false") {
            alert('not expired');
        }
    });
}, 2000);​
```

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the "accepted answer." [More info here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).